# Use awk to print largest alphanumeric grep result and create variable next in sequence

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a source file with the following information in it.

WABEL8499IPM101
WABEL8499IPM102
WABEL8499IPM103
WABEL8499IPM104
WABEL8499IPM105
WABEL8499IPM106
WABEL8499IPM107
WABEL8499IPM108

I need to be able to find the largest name in the sequence and then create a new variable with the next logical name in the sequence. I need to be able to create multiple if necessary. For example:

Use grep to search the file for WABEL8499IPM which shows all of the above results. I need to find WABEL8499IPM108 because it's the largest in the sequence and then create a new variable (how many depends on what the user inputs) with the value WABEL8499IPM109. If user inputs a quantity of 2 then I need both 109 and 110. My goal is to build a bash script to input the base name (without the last 3 digits), find the largest in the sequence and then output to a log file the next names in the sequence however many times the user needs.

I'm not really sure where to start. I can find all using grep but having difficulty finding only the largest value/sequence. The user will only input the base name because they won't know the last 3 digits. Currently I don't have any code that works.

```
SRCFILE="~/Desktop/deviceinfo.csv"  
LOGDIR="~/Desktop/"  
LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/DeviceNames.csv"  

echo -e "\n"  
echo "What is the base device name?"  
read deviceName  
echo "How many device names do you need?"  
read quantityName  
lines=$(grep -c "$deviceName" $SRCFILE)  
echo -e "\n"  
echo "There are $lines results."  
deviceResults=$(grep -F "$deviceName" $SRCFILE)  
echo -e "\n"  
echo Device Name\'s Currently Enrolled:  
echo "$deviceResults"  
echo -e "\n" 
echo "Your output file has been created."
CODE FOR CREATING OUTPUT FILE HERE
echo "$deviceName1" >> "$LOGFILE"  
echo "$deviceName2" >> "$LOGFILE"  
echo "$deviceName3" >> "$LOGFILE"
```

Would there be a way with this method to use a reference file for the input? For example if I had to research and create multiple names with different quantities could we use an input reference file for that so we don't have to type them each individually and run the script multiple times?

Comment: Welcome to SO, good try to explain your problem, could you please let us know more clearly what you are trying to so like sample of input file(if it is there) and expected output sample in CODE TAGS so that we will know full picture of your question too, cheers.

Comment: I've added an example source and output file as well as some code I've currently got. Right now I don't have code for creating the next names in the sequence and adding them to a variable to be printed to the output file. How many are output should be dependent on $quantityName.

Comment: Kindly DO NOT give links or images or attachments they are not encouraged, please paste some samples in code tags for input and output, keep it simple and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SRCFILE="~/Desktop/deviceinfo.csv"  
LOGDIR="~/Desktop/"  
LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/DeviceNames.csv"  

# base name, such as "WABEL8499IPM"
device_name=$1
# quantity, such as "2"
quantityNum=$2

# the largest in sequence, such as "WABEL8499IPM108"
max_sequence_name=$(cat $SRCFILE | grep -o -e "$device_name[0-9]*" | sort --reverse | head -n 1)

# extract the last 3digit number (such as "108") from max_sequence_name
max_sequence_num=$(echo $max_sequence_name | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev)

# creat a sequence of files starting from "WABEL8499IPM101"  if there is not any "WABEL8499IPM". 
if [ -z "$max_sequence_name" ];
then    
    max_sequence_name=device_name
    max_sequence_num=100
fi

# create new sequence_name
# such as ["WABEL8499IPM109", "WABEL8499IPM110"]
array_new_sequence_name=()
for i in $(seq 1 $quantityNum);
do
    cnum=$((max_sequence_num + i))
    array_new_sequence_name+=($(echo $device_name$cnum))
done

#CODE FOR CREATING OUTPUT FILE HERE
#for fn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]}; do touch $fn; done;

# write log
for sqn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]};
do
    echo $sqn >> $LOGFILE
done
```

Usage:

```
bash test.sh WABEL8499IPM 2
```

Result in the log file:

```
WABEL8499IPM109
WABEL8499IPM110
```

---

**EDITED**

The input reference file (input.txt) :

```
WABEL8499IPM,2
WABEL8555IPM,6
WABEL8444IPM,5
```

The driver shell script :

```
INPFIL="./input.txt"
PSRC="./test.sh"    

cat $INPFIL | while read line; 
do
    device_name=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1`
    quantity_num=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2`
    bash $PSRC $device_name $quantity_num
done;
```

Comment: Would there be a way with this method to use a reference file for the input? For example if I had to research and create multiple names with different quantities could we use an input reference file for that so we don't have to type them each individually and run the script multiple times?

Comment: Another shell script enables you to do so. I edited the answer.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this method to work. Getting a "seq: invalid floating point argument: 10\r" error. - Actually I did after reformatting the input file. It was apparently seeing something else at the end. If a name isn't in the reference file it creates the name WABEL8499IPM1. Any way to get it to create WABEL8499IPM101 if it didn't find a reference?

Comment: Well - I had it working but still can't figure out why it's seeing other stuff at the end "10\r" etc.

Comment: In my environment, I've not got any error message from this program. Please tell me your execute environment and input.txt . And to create WABEL8499IPM101, I edited the "test.sh".

Comment: macOS. Running via terminal. (#!/bin/bash). I'm actually creating a input.csv file using either excel or numbers. Sometimes it works and other times I get the "seq: invalid floating point argument: 10\r" error where 10 is the quantity. Would making this a .txt work better? It seems depending on how I create the input file it either does or doesn't see "extra characters." But either way I can't figure out what causes it. -- By the way I did get the start at 100 with your edit to test.sh. Thank you so much, you've been a lot of help and this will save me hours of work.

Comment: It is because of newline character. The "\r" of "10\r" is CR (Carriage Return) character. In macOS, newline character is "\n", but in Windows newline character is "\r\n".  So, the shell commands running on macOS don't recognize "\r" as newline character. Excel outputs "\r\n" as newline character in default setting. So, you should convert newline characters in your input.csv with "tr" command.

Comment: Is there an easy way to re-write the script so that it will fill in the gaps? For example if it finds WABEL8499IPM101,103 and 104 already in use and I enter 2 as the quantity needed that it returns 102 and 105?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
logdir="~/Desktop/"  
srcfile="$logdir/deviceinfo.csv"  
logfile="$logdir/DeviceNames.csv"  

echo
read -p "What is the base device name? " deviceName
echo
read -p "How many device names do you need? " quantityName
echo

awk -v name="$deviceName" \
  -v q="$quantityName" \
  -v lelog="$logfile" '
  $0 ~ "^"name {
    sub(name,"")
    a=a>$0?a:$0
    }
  END {
    if ( a )
        for ( i = 1 ; i <= q ; i++ )
            print name ( a + i ) >> lelog
    }
' "$srcfile"
```